# Combine multiple lists (of equal length) stored in dict into a single list of list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have this following dictionary (which essentially resembles a table):

```
tbl = {'col0':[20, 30, 22, 15, 24],
       'col1':[13, 15, 10, 14, 15],
       'col2':[52, 12, 14, 36, 23] }
```

I want to convert this to a `list of list` that combines all the list across the columns (i.e. same index elements become one list-element in list of list)

It should look somewhat like this:

```
[[20, 13, 52], [30, 15, 12], [22, 10, 14], [15, 14, 36], [24, 15, 23]]
```

it should also work for situations where my `dict` would be something like this:

```
tbl = {'col0':1.0,
       'col1':7.0,
       'col2':1.3 }

# converted into
[[1.0, 7.0, 1.3]]
```

is there a pythonic way of doing this ?  I basically need it to print a Table structure row-wise by over-riding a `__str__` method for a structure which currently stores table values in `dict` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use an unreadable double list comprehension!

```
my_list_of_lists = [[tbl[key][idx] for key in tbl] for idx in range(len(tbl[list(tbl.keys())[0]]))]
```

If you might have data without a length, you can use this instead (as long as all columns are the same length):

```
def len_checker(item):
    try:
        return len(item)
    except:
        return 0

my_list_of_lists = [[tbl[key][idx] for key in tbl] for idx in range(len(tbl[list(tbl.keys())[0]]))] if len_checker(tbl[list(tbl.keys())[0]]) else [[tbl[key] for key in tbl]]
```

Aren't these fun?

Things are a little cleaner if you can guarantee that the key `'col0'` is in your table.

```
my_list_of_lists = [[tbl[key][idx] for key in tbl] for idx in range(len(tbl['col0']))] if len_checker(tbl['col0']) else [[tbl[key] for key in tbl]]
```

In all seriousness, though, if you want clean code you should be using something like a Pandas DataFrame.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

try:
    df = DataFrame(tbl)
except:
    df = DataFrame(tbl,index=[0])
my_list_of_lists = [list(df.iloc[row]) for row in range(df.shape[0])]
```

You can use numpy too.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.vstack([np.array(tbl[key]) for key in tbl])
my_list_of_lists = [list(arr[...,col]) for col in range(arr.shape[1])]
```

Comment: I updated a question a bit which includes `dict` with scalars as well. Will that work here ? I'm afraid not. I get an error `float is not iterable` on your suggestion.

Comment: @lamo_738 I added a version that works in that case :)

Comment: Sorry, but i'm working on a library which has zero dependencies apart from numpy. So, I do not want to rely on Pandas, but yeah that works.

Comment: @lamo_738 I added a clean numpy version for you too.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is handy for this:

```
>>> list(zip(*tbl.values()))
[(20, 13, 52), (30, 15, 12), (22, 10, 14), (15, 14, 36), (24, 15, 23)]
```

For a list of lists instead of tuples, you can use a generator expression:

```
>>> list(list(x) for x in zip(*tbl.values()))
[[20, 13, 52], [30, 15, 12], [22, 10, 14], [15, 14, 36], [24, 15, 23]]
```

Comment: would this also work if I have something like this ```tbl = {'col0': 1.0, 'col1': 2.0, 'col3': 3.0} ----> [[1.0, 2.0,3.0]]``` ? It gives error saying float is not iterable. workaround for this ?

Comment: If the individual values aren't lists, do you want the result to still be a list of lists of single elements, or just a flat list?

Comment: Also, the one you suggested gives `list of tuples`

Comment: I still need it list of list. The reason is I'm trying to overwrite a `__str__` method for displaying a table structure stored in `dict` for some other reason. Hence, I need the values of rows in a list to print it as ```'|'.join(row_list[i])```

Comment: I found a solution to handle the non-list entries of the `dict` , but can you suggest how to slightly change your answer to get `list of list` rather than `list of tuple` ?